# css td margin collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a table with 1 row of 3 cells,
When increasing the size of the page, "Ctrl +" , the content of the 2nd cell expands on a second line, and makes the color of the first cell not fill the entire first cell. Same thing happens with the button as I modify its height it makes the other cells lose control!  Somehow, the color does not stretch. How can i fix this? It seems to be some sort of margin-collapse issue.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="background-color:yellow">
     <span> hello world how are you {{ name }}</span>
    </td>
    <td>  
<span> I am a very long paragraph which will break on a second line when i increase the size of my browser page and i will cause the first cell color to not stretch and fill the entire cell.. iam a mad man! hehe</span>
    </td>
<td>
    <button> </button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: why you would style thing with page zoomed in?

Comment: anyone can zoom or decrease the size of the page..the styling shouldnt go away..

Comment: A couple of screenshots wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `span` is NOT inside a table cell which is invalid HTML. If you put it inside the second cell, everything behaves as expected:

```css
button {
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:yellow">
      <span> hello world how are you {{ name }}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
    <span> I am a very long paragraph which will break on a second line when i increase the size of my browser page and i will cause the first cell color to not stretch and fill the entire cell.. iam a mad man! hehe</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>The button</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry this was my mistake when writing the question, it actually is inside the <td></td> tags in my code.. thanks though

Comment: still, your code does not show the problem you describe

Comment: I added a button text and height to it ... (?)

Comment: the issue here is that the first cells also breaks on 2 line, therefore the issue is not really replicated; i figured someone would know on top of the head what the issue is. the actual code is full of angular bindings, and i am not allowed to post it here, nor would it actually be easy to post the entire piece of code and controllers..etc..and make it replicate... but thanks